# jQuery Date Picker disable all days up to 7 days away

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to find a way to disable all dates that are not at least 7 days away from the current date. The following just allows the next 7 days. I need to disable the next 6 days from the current date and allow everything after that. Is there a way accomplish this?

```
$('#intmoveDate').datepicker({
inline: true,
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
changeFirstDay: false,
minDate: 0,
maxDate: "7D"

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `minDate: "7D"` (no max date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you a minimum date of 7 days away with no maxmimum date.

```
$('#intmoveDate').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    changeFirstDay: false,
    minDate: +7
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was exactly what I was looking for. I was obviously trying to do too much. I don't know why I thought that I somehow had to combine min and max date. Thanks again.